# How to Mock Template(.ftl file) in Junit

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, mocking, mockito

a.  We have the templates in src/main/resources/templates in eclipse.

b.  Add a Junit for these templates for the possible scenarios.

How to add Junit For this templates. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

What is that you want to test using JUnit here?
When you say you want to add JUnit for the templates, are you testing the template itself? If so, why do you think you need to mock the templates? You should not be mocking the unit which you are testing. 
Would you like to reframe your question?

Comment: If i go for add junit for template. How to add this .please help